# Mypy rejects type objects created with `type(name, (bases,), {})`

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.6, mypy

I'm having some trouble getting mypy to accept type objects. I am 
convinced I'm just doing it wrong but my google searches have not led me to any answers so far.

```
class Good(object):
    a = 1

def works(thing: Good):
    print(thing.a)

o = Good()
works(o)

Bad = type('Bad', (object, ), dict(a=1))

def fails_mypy(thing: Bad):
    print(thing.a)

s = Bad()
fails_mypy(s)
```

Things constructed like '`Good`' are ok, while things constructed like '`Bad`' fail mypy checks with:

```
error: Invalid type "test.Bad"
error: Bad? has no attribute "a"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [Unsupported Python Features](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Unsupported-Python-Features) section of `mypy`s wiki, runtime creation of classes like this isn't currently supported. It cannot understand what `Bad` is in your function definition. Using `reveal_type(Good)` and `reveal_type(Bad)` when executing `mypy` should make this clear.

An approach to silence these is by using `Any`. Either using Python 3.6 variable annotation syntax:

```
Bad: Any = type('Bad', (), {'a':1})
```

or, with Python < 3.6:

```
Bad = type('Bad', (), {'a':1}) # type: Any
```

<sup><sup>(in both cases `Any` should first be imported from `typing`)</sup></sup>

of course, this basically means that your function now accepts anything. A price to pay, but that's what you get with dynamic languages; since `Bar` is defined at runtime, it *can* theoretically be anything :-)

Comment: If your dynamically created classes have some kind of common interface, you could create an abstract base class that encapsulates that and use it as one of the bases. Then, instead of using `Any`, you can use `Type[MyBaseClass]`. (The same applies if there's some other common denominator.) It's not much of an improvement, but it's marginally better than `Any`.